# CryptGetProvParam and multithreaded programs

Tags: windows, security, cryptoapi

The MSDN documentation for [CryptGetProvParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380196(v=vs.85).aspx) says

*This function must not be used on a thread of a multithreaded program.*

I'm hoping there is some set of conditions under which it can be used that way. Does anyone have any experience in this area and can tell me a work-around?

Thanks.

Comment: Nowadays, *all* programs are multi-threaded, because Windows creates and uses extra threads even if your code doesn't.  I'm not sure what that sentence is supposed to mean.  It is also strange that some of the queries explicitly say that they aren't thread-safe, which makes no sense if the function can't be used from a multi-threaded program anyway.  (I suspect it is just nonsense, but I can't state that as a fact.)

Comment: Yes, it's a poser. Maybe it was written in the Windows 3 era? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the MSDN documentation is written by interns and the quality is not always great. They are clearly talking about issues related to calling this function from multiple threads at the same time, not just having multiple threads in the process.

If you look at some of the query values and how the API is designed it should be easy to spot the queries that **cannot** work with multiple threads. Anything that uses `CRYPT_FIRST`/`NEXT` (`PP_*ENUM*`) will have to rely on some internal state to remember "where it is". These queries have the thread warning in their description as well.

This does not mean that the other queries are thread safe but I would imagine that they are. You could debug the functions but things might change over time/versions and parts of the crypto system is extensible as well so you can never truly know without official information from Microsoft. You can add feedback to the MSDN page and hope that they update it.

Comment: Funny, I didn't even think about the first/next aspect of it. I thought there was some dark, unmentionable aspect of the crypto api I wasn't party to. I will post feedback on that page. Thanks.